# Получить значение из текста

Tags: c#

Есть текст "myserver.com/?download_file=41&wccc_key_email=email&key=key"
Как получить из всего этого только значение после "/?download_file" ? В моем случае это 41.

Comment: Как-то всё проще должно выходить: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @VladD Ну, C# это не пайтон)

Comment: @KitScribe: Да, и поэтому парсинг на регулярках в C# не принят.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать регулярные выражения.

Это, например, я писал для поиска домена, включая поддомены в ссылках:

```
"(\w+[-]*\w*[.])+(\w+)"
```

А такое найдёт слеш и все соединяющие "&":

```
"[\/&]"
```

Ну а так можно будет получить всё, включая домен любой глубины до знака вопроса (не включительно):

```
"(\w+[-]*\w*[.])+(\w+)[^?]+"
```

Кстати, регулярные выражения возвращают не только найденные строки, но и стартовый и конечный индекс найденного относительно исходной строки. Думаю, это будет вам полезно.

Comment: Последнее можно сократить до "[^?]+" и таким образом мы найдём и то, что идёт до вопросительного знака, и то, что идёт после него. Но я оставил поиск домена любой глубины для того, чтобы удостовериться, что на вход дана была ссылка

Answer (score 0):

Должно работать что-то такое:

```
var uriString = "http://myserver.com/?download_file=41&wccc_key_email=email&key=key";
var query = new Uri(uriString).Query;
var collection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);
var downloadFileValue = collection["download_file"]; // null если не найдено
Console.WriteLine(downloadFileValue ?? "нет такого значения");
```

Вам понадобится подключить `System.Web`.

Comment: Сорри, проверить не могу. Надеюсь, работает.